# Getting user photos using Facebook login on android

Tags: android, facebook, photos

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.0 and I'm able to login a user using Facebook login on android using this -

```
info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);    
loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);    


  loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText("User ID:  " +
                        loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" +
                        "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });
```

But how can I go to get user's photos ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{Facebook_id}/picture?type=large
```

for example Mark Zuckerberg's Facebook ID is 4 so you can use it like this :

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large

In your case you need to put it inside the onSuccess :

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            info.setText("User ID:  " +
                    userId + "\n" +
                    "Auth Token: " + token);
            String imageUrl = String.format("https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large", userId);
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how and where to use the code you gave ? I couldn't understand how to use this from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood the concept. And it works too. Accepted as answer.

Comment: Can you tell how can I go about getting all the photos in a user's profile ?

Comment: @Gissipi_453 That's a different question so you should open a new question about it :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm opening a new question.

Comment: I opened a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666627/getting-all-the-photos-in-a-users-profile-using-facebook-sdk-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [User Photos API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) reference.

Comment: Can you tell me how and where to use this in the code ? I couldn't understand how to use this from the documentation.