# Getting Facebook photos in android from Graph API URL

Tags: android, facebook, photos

On android I'm using Facebook SDK 4.0. I want to get all photos of a user logged in via Facebook login.

I have this URL

https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID/albums?access_token=TOKEN

How do I parse and generate images to be viewed in a ListView ?

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665942/getting-user-photos-using-facebook-login-on-android

Answer (score 1):

set `Bundle` for extra parameters like crate a `bundle` for required parameters ex:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id, picture");
```

Then set it to `GraphRequest`.

Comment: You may add some more context and a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you have to used below code to get all photos of user.

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/photos",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: And can you tell how to parse and load the images in a ListView ?

Comment: @Gissipi_453 you have to parse json as a simple jsonParsing that we have used for parsing json and for load image you have to used universal image loader

Comment: Thank you bhai. But can you give an example of a simple jsonParsing ? How do I get image links from the code above ? After I get URLs, I can update the ListView myself.