# Not getting photos links when parsing Facebook graph API request on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I'm trying to get user photos link on android using Facebook SDK 4.0 and graph API.
I wrote this code to parse and get photos link -

```
new GraphRequest(

            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + userId + "/photos",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                            JSONObject json = null;

                            try {
                                json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTracegetJSONObject();
                            }
                            JSONArray jarray = null;
                            try {
                                jarray = json.getJSONArray("data"); 

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 

                            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                                oneAlbum = null;
                                try {
                                    oneAlbumURL1 = jarrayjson.getJSONObjectgetString(i"url");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    einfo.printStackTracesetText(URL1.toString());
                                }

                                String URL1 = null; // 
                                try {
                                  URL1 = String.valueOf(oneAlbum.getJSONObject("link"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Log.d("", URL1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

But its neither showing any error nor getting any URLs/links. Can anyone tell whats wrong here ?

Comment: Duplicate (number three by now) of your own previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665942/getting-user-photos-using-facebook-login-on-android – please stop **spamming** this site with is basically the same question over and over again.

Comment: I'm not spamming. These are genuine questions. These are not duplicate questions. 1st one was to get single user profile photo, 2nd one was about Graph API URL and 3rd one is about a parsing error. And please help me with this question. I'm having a tough time. After this is solved, I'm done for work.

Comment: @Gissipi_453 Is my answer works for you..?

Comment: @V.J. Its working now. I edited my code as per your answer. And just replaced "url" with "source" as per Facebook Graph API documentation to parse the response. Thanks for being so patient. I accepted your answer and upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @Gissipi_453.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per new Facebook api v2.4 you need to pass the fields parameter with your facebook api url.

Like: &fields=source,id,picture

i.e.:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userId/photos?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=source,id,picture
```

You will get the image url in source and picture tag..

**EDIT**

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "source,id,picture");

AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + userId + "/photos",
                    parameters,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
```

**EDIT-2:**

```
public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
    JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
    JSONArray jarray = null;
    try {
        jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How do i use this with my code ? Or can you give example of the code using your answer ?

Comment: Now it has got one error. Its giving null point exception for -->                           jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: You need to debug your code.. I have tried to resolve facebook related issue.

Comment: yes i did that. Im just stuck with this error --> cannot resolve constructor 'JSONObject(com.facebook.GraphResponse)'   for the line 'JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);'

Comment: See my edit-1. You can get the json object with 
JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();

Answer (score 0):

As per answer given by V.J., I edited my code and it works perfectly fine now. Just replaced "url" with "source".

```
new GraphRequest(

                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                         "/" + userId + "/photos",
                        parameters,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                json = response.getJSONObject();
                                Log.d("json value", json.toString());

                                try {

                                    jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){

                                    try {
                                        oneAlbum = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        URL1 = String.valueOf(oneAlbum.getJSONObject("source"));
                                        info.setText(URL1);
                                        Log.d("got URLSSSs", URL1.toString());
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();
```